# Тормозит ProgressBar

Tags: android, progress-bar

Есть приложение, которое при первом запуске скачивает данные с базы сервера. Для загрузки использую **Volley**. Добавил ProgressBar, чтобы пользователь не глядел в пустое окно.

ProgressBar почти не шевелится до тех пор, пока не выполнятся запросы Volley. Чуть сдвигается от первоначального положения и все. Насколько я понял, Volley асинхронен.

В чем может быть проблема?

UPD. Добавляю код.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

public LinearLayout cartSticker;

DbHelper dbHelper;
Cursor c;

ListView itemsList;
GridView itemsGrid;
ListView menu;

DrawerLayout drawer;
Toolbar toolbar;
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;

public Core core;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LayoutInflater lInflater = getLayoutInflater();

    dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);

    core = Core.getInstance();
    core.setContext(this);
    core.setHelper(dbHelper);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    cartSticker = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.cart_items_sticker_wrapper);

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    toggle = new android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    menu = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.cats_list);
    menu.addHeaderView(lInflater.inflate(R.layout.cat_list_header, null), null, true);
    menu.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            VHolder holder = (VHolder) view.getTag();
            if (holder == null) {
                showMainPage();
                drawer.closeDrawers();
            } else {
                int catId = holder.id;
                openCat(catId);
            }
        }
    });

    updateCartSticker(dbHelper.getCartItemsCount());


    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
        }
    });
    drawer.closeDrawers();
    pB = new ProgressBar(getApplicationContext());
}

ProgressBar pB;
public void showLoader() {
    AbsListView.LayoutParams lP = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(70, 70);
    ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.loader_wrapper)).addView(pB, lP);
}
public void hideLoader() {
    ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.loader_wrapper)).removeAllViews();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    new DataLoader().execute("");
}

private void buildMenu() {
    String[] from = {"name"};
    int[] to = {R.id.name};
    c = dbHelper.getCat();

    MenuCursorAdapter mca = new MenuCursorAdapter(this, c, 1);
    menu.setAdapter(mca);
}

public void showMainPage() {
    Fragment fr = new MainFragment();

    FragmentManager fM = getFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction fTr = fM.beginTransaction();
    fTr.replace(R.id.main_content, fr);
    fTr.commit();
}


public void buildProducts(int catId, int type) {

    Fragment fragment = new ListFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("catId", catId);
    args.putInt("type", type);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction fTr = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fTr.replace(R.id.main_content, fragment);
    fTr.addToBackStack(null);
    fTr.commit();
}

public void openCat(int id) {
    Category cat = dbHelper.getCategory(id);
    toolbar.setTitle(cat.name);
    buildProducts(id, 0);
    drawer.closeDrawers();
}

public void openCart() {
    {

        Fragment fragment = new CartFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        FragmentTransaction fTr = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fTr.replace(R.id.main_content, fragment);
        fTr.addToBackStack(null);
        fTr.commit();

        toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getText(R.string.app_cart));
    }
}

public void openProduct(int id) {
    Fragment fragment = new ProductFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("productId", id);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction fTr = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fTr.replace(R.id.main_content, fragment);
    fTr.addToBackStack(null);
    fTr.commit();

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_cart) {
        openCart();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

public void loadFromServer() {
    showLoader();
    RequestQueue rQ = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    StringRequest catsRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, Core.catsUrl,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    dbHelper.updateCategories(response);
                    buildMenu();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    StringRequest prodsRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, Core.prodsUrl,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    dbHelper.updateProducts(response);
                    buildMenu();
                    showMainPage();


                    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("gorillagym_update_data_flag", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor spe = sp.edit();

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    rQ.add(catsRequest);
    rQ.add(prodsRequest);
}

public void updateFromServer() {

    String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("gorillagym_update_data_flag", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String lastUpdateDate = sp.getString("last_update_date", date);


    RequestQueue rQ = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    StringRequest updateRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, Core.updateUrl + "&date=" + lastUpdateDate,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {

                        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean status = jObject.getBoolean("status");
                        String lastTime = jObject.getString("lastTime");
                        if (status) {
                            dbHelper.updateData(response);

                            SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("gorillagym_update_data_flag", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor spe = sp.edit();

                            spe.putString("last_update_date", lastTime);
                            spe.apply();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    rQ.add(updateRequest);
}

public void updateData() {
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("gorillagym_update_data_flag", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (sp.getBoolean("first_install", true)) {
         loadFromServer();
    } else {
        showMainPage();
        updateFromServer();
    }
}

public void updateCartSticker(int count) {
    if (count <= 0) {
        cartSticker.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ((TextView) cartSticker.findViewById(R.id.cart_items_sticker)).setText("");
    } else {
        cartSticker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ((TextView) cartSticker.findViewById(R.id.cart_items_sticker)).setText(String.valueOf(count));
    }
}

public class DataLoader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    public DataLoader () {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        updateData();
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Привёл бы фрагмент кода хотя бы

Comment: Проблема в вашем коде. Это была демо-версия ответа. Полную версию вы получите приведя ваш код.

Answer (score 1):

Могу предположить, что ваш Volley не достаточно синхронизирован.

Попробуйте сделать тестовый `AsyncTask`(Тестовый!использовать его плохая идея - проблем много с поворотом).

В нем в `doInBackground` делаете необходимые вам операции, и через `publishProgress()`обновляете состояние `progressBar`.

Если все будет идти гладко - значит у вас все происходило в главном потоке, и нужно подумать о асинхронности самому.

Comment: Я хотел просто добавить бесконечный прогресс бар, и скрыть его после выполнения запросов. Отображать прогресс не требуется. 

Сейчас попробую AsyncTask протестить, спасибо за совет.

Comment: @asmproger тогда все становится еще проще - бесконечный прогресс бар представляет собой кружок, либо линию. Поэтому нужно просто выявить момент, когда его показывать, а когда скрывать. Даже не нужно на порции разбивать.

Comment: Начал пробовать AsyncTask, и обнаружил, что проблема не в запросе, а в его обработке. Мне с сервера приходит JSON, около 260 элементов. И я в цикле его разбираю, и пихаю в запрос. Вот тут и начинаются тормоза, и прогресс бар не движется. Когда убираю обработку - все нормально работает, и скрывается. Буду разбираться дальше.